# How to make sure to get specific char variables

Tags: java, while-loop, char

I need this program to keep on asking for `cardChosen1`, until the user gives an answer of something between 'a' and 'h'. I know I could just put

```
while (cardChosen1 == 'a' && cardChosen1 == 'b' && cardChosen1 == 'c' &&...
```

Etc. But I would prefer there to be a more concise way. I want it not only block letters, but also symbols and numbers

I've tried the following:

```
 while (cardChosen1 > 'a' && cardChosen1 < 'h')
                {
                    System.out.println ("Hey");
                    cardChosen1 = e.getKeyChar ();
                }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Try using ASCII code for particular input given by user then the comparison > OR < makes sense.

Comment: You probably want >= and <= instead of > and <, unless you want to not include 'a' and 'h'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the right form of what you typed above as the suggested answer has to be like this:

```
while (cardChosen1 == 'a' || cardChosen1 == 'b' || cardChosen1 == 'c' || ... || cardChosen1 == 'h')
```

because you need a character to be "a" ***or*** "b" ***or*** "c" ... but what you entered wants the character to be ***all*** of characters from 'a' to 'h' which is impossible.

Now for your concise way. You are close to the answer and with some minor changes it will work. But it's more readable (in Java) to use *Explicit Type Cast* (of course it's optional). Like this:

```
while ((int) cardChosen1 >= (int) 'a' || (int) cardChosen1 <= (int) 'h')
```

Also notice about `>=` and `<=` signs as you accept the answer if it's 'a' or 'h' itself.
And finally you must convert `&&` to `||` as I explained above.

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there. The problem is that you loop while you **do** get an answer between `'a'` and `'h'`, and you wanted to loop **as long as you don't** get such an answer. Just slap on a negation operator (`!`), and you should be fine:

```
while (!(cardChosen1 > 'a' && cardChosen1 < 'h')) {
```

Better yet, you can simplify this statement with some boolean algebra:

```
while (cardChosen1 <= 'a' || cardChosen1 > 'h')) {
```

Answer (score 1):

this condition is universally `false`

```
while (cardChosen1 == 'a' && cardChosen1 == 'b' && cardChosen1 == 'c' &&...
```

this condition will work but I would prefer you to create a `Set<Character>` and look up if it exists in `Set` by `contains()`

```
 while (cardChosen1 > 'a' && cardChosen1 < 'h')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for [ASCII codes](http://www.bibase.com/ascii.htm).

for example if you want to check `a` to `h` range try

```
(int)cardChosen1 > 97 || (int)cardChosen1 < 122
```